# Local azure function runtime fails to retrieve a token from the included credentials despite being logged in

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'd like to read blobs in a storage container, based off this [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-cli%2Csign-in-visual-studio-code#list-the-blobs-in-a-container). I've already been assigned the role of `Storage Account Contributor`.  Using VS code, I followed the tutorial (in VS code) by starting with `az login`, then start my environment localy, and finally executing the function.  I get the following warning:

```
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
     EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
     ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
     SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
     AzureCliCredential: Failed to invoke Azure CLI
To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.
```

my code, following the tutorial, looks like:

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def main(req=None) -> func.HttpResponse:
    account_url = "https://<name>.blob.core.windows.net"
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('<name>')

    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for b in blob_list:
        return func.HttpResponse(f'{b.name}')
```

Not sure what else I should do if I've already done the `az login` part.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

```
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
     EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.
     ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
     SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
     AzureCliCredential: Failed to invoke Azure CLI
To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot.
```

The above error suggest you need to define at least one of the credential like **`environmentcredential,ManagedIdentitycredential,sharedtokencachecredential,AzureCliCredential.`** to retrieve token.

You can follow this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#troubleshoot-defaultazurecredential-authentication-issues) to retrieve the token with credential.
I followed the document in terminal I tried **`az login`** for signing in and used the below code to get the list of blobs using Http trigger function.

**Code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def main(req=None) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    account_url = "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net" 
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
    container_name="test"
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    #blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    blobs=[]
    for b in container_client.list_blobs():
        blobs.append(b.name)
        logging.info(b.name)
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Listed blobs in container: {blobs}")
```

The above code executed successfully and listed blobs from the storage container.

**Console:**
[image]

**Browser:**
[image]

Comment: which credentials did you store in local.settings.json? I've stored AZURE_USERNAME
AZURE_PASSWORD but it seems like I'm being asked for more, however some of them, like AZURE_CLIENT_ID I don't have access to, since this local script isn't part of an app. It's also strange that it's not finding AzureCliCredential despite `az login`.

Comment: Try with connection string once.

Comment: connection string works, but that is not the same as DefaultAzureCredential.

Comment: You can check my ![local.settings.json](https://i.imgur.com/jvX13X7.png) 
here I tried with **`az login`** it is authenticated with my azureclicredential.

Comment: That configuration with UseDevelopmentStorage doesn't work for me.